# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $|H|<|K|$, does that imply that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm currently doing my best to teach myself group theory from a book ([Groups, Rings and Galois Theory by Victor P. Snaith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812385762); for those who are interested. I highly recommend to anyone just starting out). I'm learning about subgroups/quotient groups, and an interesting idea popped into mind:

Since both $H$ and $K$ must contain the identity to be groups, and they are both subgroups of $G$, my intuition says that either $H$ must contain $K$ or $K$ must contain $H$. As in, there can't be any elements of the smaller subgroup that do not exist in the larger. I've done my best to prove it on paper, but I'm still too new to successfully do the algebra I've seen in other proofs. I've also tried to create a counter example, but I can't quite do that either.

Can anyone help me out? Either by guiding me towards a proof or by providing a counter example?

Thanks!

Comment: What if $G=H\times K$, with $|H|<|K|$? Then the *only* element they have in common is the identity. (Because of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, 5xum's example below is an instance of this class of examples.) My intuition is that subgroups are kinds of "smears" jutting out from the identity within the group, but not necessarily in the same "direction" (so not necessarily overlapping).

Comment: @runway44 oh I like that!! That helps a lot with my understanding. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Take $G=\mathbb Z_6$, take $H=\{0,3\}$ and $K=\{0,2,4\}$. Then clearly, $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups of $G$, and $|H|<|K|$, however, $H$ is not a subgroup of $K$.

Comment: Haha thanks!! I avoided using Mod groups because I thought it would be... "cheating" somehow? I'm very new to this - I guess someone has to come on here and ask the dumb questions for people to google later 

Answer (score 3):

This is false.   For instance consider $S_3$.  We have three subgroups of order two: $\langle (12)\rangle, \langle (23)\rangle, \langle (13)\rangle $.

And one of order three $\langle(123)\rangle $.  It's easy to see that a subgroup of order two can't be contained in one of order three,  because this violates Lagrange.

Think of Sylow subgroups,  for example.   Having smaller order certainly doesn't imply containment. Since Sylow subgroups for different $p$ have relatively prime orders, they intersect trivially (in the identity).

Enjoy your studies.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another small order counterexample. In $D_4$ dihedral of order $8$, of generators $r$ and $s$, consider the subgroups $K:=\{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$ and $H:=\{1,s\}$.